# Matching Patterns with Quotes in Java

Tags: java, regex, string, compare, matching

I was wondering how I can use Patterns to check if regex matches the string? The problem im having is that I want the text in quotes to act like one word, like in the second case.

The String:

```
message "the id of %type of the clicked block% is %id of the clicked block%."
```

Syntax:

```
message .*
```

Should Return:

```
true
```

**Another Case:**
The String:

```
send "You are not allowed to use this command."
```

Syntax:

```
send .* to .*
```

Should Return:

```
False
```

Comment: You can use `\"` to escape quotes. However your second case is incorrect, as it should be true because `.*` includes two things: 1) `.` which is "Match any character except line breaks" and 2) `*` which is "Match 0 or more of the preceding token." A quote does not stop a match from occurring.

Comment: @signus I was just showing what I want

Comment: You cannot "make" them act as one word, however you can make everything in quotes a match group or you can simply focus on matching data inside or outside the data inside of the quotes like so `send \".*\" to`.

Comment: @Signus Should that not be `\".*?\"` instead (or `\"[^"]\"`)?

Comment: @GáborBakos it doesn't have to exclusively be, since that is a lazy match. Though including the lazy quantifier is perfectly fine.

Comment: I was just looking for a much better way of doing it

Answer (score 0):

As noted in my above comment, and hopefully this answers your question, but you can simply terminate at the quotes and match anything between the quotes like so:

Given your examples:

```
message "the id of %type of the clicked block% is %id of the clicked block%."

send "You are not allowed to use this command."
```

The regex(es) that matches both of these includes using `\".*\"` which matches everything between the quotes (escaped by `\`).

```
\w+ \".*\"
```

So using `send \".*\" to` would be false in that case.

Introducing match groups:

```
send (\".*\")
```